# How to split long strings over multiple lines in yaml without introducing whitespace characters

Tags: yaml

In yaml, there are multiple ways to format a long string over multiple lines. For example:

Input:

```
example:
  string1: An example of a long string that is split across 
    two lines
```

Output (as JSON):

```
{
  "example": {
    "string1": "An example of a long string that is split across two lines"
   }
}
```

Or using explicit folded syntax:

```
example:
  string1: >
    An example of a long string that is split across
    two lines
```

Output:

```
{
  "example": {
    "string1": "An example of a long string that is split across two lines"
   }
}
```

Or using literal syntax:

```
example:
  string1: |
    An example of a long string that is split across
    two lines
```

Output:

```
{
  "example": {
    "string1": "An example of a long string that is split across\ntwo lines"
   }
}
```

In all examples that I can find, it seems that the resulting string will either have a space or a newline character inserted between each line. However, I would like to write a very long yaml string over several lines where no whitespace is inserted into the resulting line. Is this possible?

My requirement:

```
example:
  string1: Oneverylongunbrokenlinethatmustnotcon
    tainanyresultingwhitespaceintheoutput
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "example": {
    "string1": "Oneverylongunbrokenlinethatmustnotcontainanyresultingwhitespaceintheoutput"
   }
}
```

Does such syntax exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have omitted the double-quoted scalar style, which is exactly what you need:

```yaml
example:
  string1: "Oneverylongunbrokenlinethatmustnotcon\
    tainanyresultingwhitespaceintheoutput"
```

A double-quoted scalar is the only scalar style in YAML that allows being broken into multiple lines at any position. This is done by escaping the linebreak. Would you not escape the linebreak, you would get a space just like with most of the other scalar styles.

This does not work with any other style because only double-quoted scalars process escape sequences.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much. I read through the Yaml 1.2 spec and couldn't see this variation so was expecting the answer to be "no it's not possible".